# Не получается добавить в домен FreeIPA сервер под RedOS

Tags: astra-linux, freeipa

В-общем, возникла проблемка.

Я поднял контроллер домена FreeIPA на ОС Astra Linux, и любые серваки спокойно добавляются в домен. Даже когда мне пришлось пересоздать контроллер домена (изменив там буквально название и убрав тире с тайтла), те серваки, что были под первоначальным доменом, спокойно внедрились и в новый.

Но вот серваки под RedOS наотрез отказываются добавляться в домен. Я даже пробовал создавать абсолютно чистые серваки под RedOS, и пытался добавить их в домен FreeIPA (через команду ipa-client-install --mkhomedir --enable-dns-updates), но каждый раз они выдают следующую ошибку:

ipa-client-install failed

name must match '^[a-z][_a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]$|^[a-z]$'; got 'x-ald-aud-mask'

причем этот 'x-ald-***' постоянно меняется рандомным образом на другие статусы:

'x-ald-devac-status'

'x-ald-mic-level'

Я понятия не имею, что это за санскритские шифры, и почему именно под RedOS серваки ни в какую не хотят добавляться в домен FreeIPA, более того, почему они вообще пытаются подключиться к ALD (Astra Linux Directory), хотя этого ALD на контроллере домена вообще нет (проверял командой sudo autoremove ald).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Если серверы под Astra Linux спокойно включаются в домен FreeIPA, в то время как под RedOS никак?